# Setting content length of an HTTP POST request

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-content-length

I am trying to make a Http POST request using apache HTTP client. I am trying to copy contents of an HTTP POST request (received at my application) to another HTTP POST request (initiated from my application to another URL). Code is shown below:

```
httpPost = new HttpPost(inputURL);
// copy headers
for (Enumeration<String> e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
      String headerName = e.nextElement().toString(); 
      httpPost.setHeader(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
}

BufferedInputStream clientToProxyBuf = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream());
BasicHttpEntity basicHttpEntity = new BasicHttpEntity();
basicHttpEntity.setContent(clientToProxyBuf);
basicHttpEntity.setContentLength(clientToProxyBuf.available());

httpPost.setEntity(basicHttpEntity);

HttpResponse responseFromWeb = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Basically, I am trying to implement a proxy application which will get a url as parameter, froward the request to the URL and then serve pages etc in custom look and feel.

Here `request` is HttpServletRequest. I am facing problem in setting content length. Through debugging I found out that `clientToProxyBuf.available()` is not giving me correct length of input stream and I am getting Http error 400 IE and `Error 354 (net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH): The server unexpectedly closed the connection` in chrome.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was rather simple and very obvious. I just needed to get content length from header as:

```
basicHttpEntity.setContentLength(Integer.parseInt(request.getHeader("Content-Length")));
```

Comment: I am using StringEntity class in my application. How should we set content Length in StringEntity ?

Answer (score 1):

The `available()` function doesn't provide the actual length of the content of the stream, rather

> Returns the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream without blocking. (From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#available%28%29))

I would suggest you to first read the whole content from the stream, and then set that to the content, rather than passing the stream object. That way, you will also have the actual length of the content.

Comment: yes but then it will consume my inputstream making it useless for further use ?

Comment: reading content from stream do make it use less for the further request. I don't think it would work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I meant to say that rather than passing the stream, pass the content.